# OAuth2: What exactly is the "client"

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

In the context of OAuth2, I would like to know exactly which component(s) of my application is considered to be the "client".

Below are the relevant exerts from [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)

---

section 1.1:

> **client**
>
> An application making protected resource requests on behalf of the resource owner and with its authorization.  The term "client" does not imply any particular implementation characteristics (e.g., whether the application executes on a server, a desktop, or other devices).

section 2.1:

> A **client** may be implemented as a **distributed set of components**, each with a different client type and security context (e.g., a distributed client with both a confidential server-based component and a public browser-based component).  If the authorization server does not provide support for such clients or does not provide guidance with regard to their registration, the client SHOULD register each component as a separate client.

---

**Scenario 1**:

- My application (A) consists of a browser-based front-end (component A1) and a back-end API (component A2).
- The back-end (A2) acquires an access token (*Authorization Code Grant*) from Google's authorization server (G1) in order to access Google's resource server (G2)

Which of the following statements is/are correct?

1. "client" refers to (A). (A) is confidential and consists of a public component (A1) and a confidential component (A2).
2. "client" refers to (A2). (A2) is a confidential client.
3. It is incorrect to refer to (A1) as a client since (A1) doesn't make protected resource requests to (G2).

**Scenario 2**:

- My application (A) consists of a browser-based front-end (component A1) and a back-end API (component A2).
- The browser-based front-end (A1) acquires an access token (*Implicit Grant*) from Google's authorization server (G1) in order to access Google's resource server (G2)

Which of the following statements is/are correct?

1. "client" refers to (A). (A) is a public client and consists of a public component (A1) and a confidential component (A2).
2. "client" refers to (A1). (A1) is a public client.
3. It is incorrect to refer to (A2) as a client since (A2) doesn't make protected resource requests to (G2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scenario 1, component A1 is not the client as it does not access protected resources from Google. But component A2 is the client. And it is a protected client as it does not expose client credentials to resource owner (simply the application user). From your end point, both A1 and A2 is a single entity (a single application). But this is not the case for authorization server.

In scenario 2, component A1 obtain tokens and it consume the Google resources as well. So, from authorization server perspective, A1 is the client. And it is a public client as it cannot protect client credentials if any (it's browser based.!). Like before, from your end, A1 and A2 is a single entity.

Now think about a scenario where you need to consume Google services from both A1 and A2 components. Now you have the option to register two clients because from authorization server perspective, it see two different entities. One can protect credentials and other cannot. By doing so you fully utilise OAuth client types. To do this, auth. server may facilitate some features (which I'm also not fully aware). It could be something like ability to register two redirect URLs per one client. Or to use same client identity for confidential and public client.

Comment: Thanks Kavindu. Does that mean that in section 1.1 *client* refers to a single component (i.e. authorization server's perspective) whereas in section 2.1 *client* refers to all components combined (A)?

Comment: According to what I have understood from the spec., yes section 1.1 define the client entity (without talking about implementation details). And section 2.1 define different client types and how they could be formed. And yes section 2.1 refer to all components and define the approach to adopt OAuth 2.0 on them.